# Does an EventSystem need to be attached to a GameObject in order to work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, events

Ok so here is my EventSystem script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class EventSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static EventSystem instance;
    public event Action onDead;
    public event Action onScore;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void onDeadTrigger()
    {
        if (onDead != null) { onDead(); }

    }
    public void onScoreTrigger()
    {
        if (onScore != null) { onScore(); }

    }
}
```

I think because it isn't related to a GameObject ( it doesn't have to be attached to a GameObject in order to work ). **Then if EventSystem doesn't inherit from MonoBehaviour, will this make any difference? and in addition, can we use Scriptable Object ?**

And another small question that isn't related to the title but I'm a little bit confused about this.

I'm in the process of making Flappy Bird clone, when the bird touches the empty space between the pipes ( the trigger area ) then he scores a point. Which script should I invoke the Event ( the bird script or the score script attached to the trigger )
When the bird enters the trigger area **both OnTriggerEnter2D will be called on both scripts** so if I don't organize this well, my code will become spaghetti

Comment: Regarding your additional question: it doesn't matter that much, just make sure you do it once. Maybe putting it in the score script would be slightly better, so the player code won't grow too big and it would follow single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suggestions:**

In your case you don't need to inherit it from monoBehavior you can simply make class static and then you won't even need an instance of it so basically what I mean to say is make your class something like this:

```cs
using System;

public static class EventSystem {

    public static event Action OnDead;
    public static event Action OnScore;

    public static void OnDeadTrigger() => OnDead?.Invoke();

    public static void OnScoreTrigger() => OnScore?.Invoke();

    public static void ResetEvents() {
      
       OnDead = null;
       OnScore = null;
    }

}
```

So then you simply call it like this in any of your monobehaviours (or any where)

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class CollisionHandler : MonoBehavior {

    private void OnCollisionEnter( collision other ) {
       
        if( other.gameObject.CompareTag( "coin" ) ) {

            EventSystem.OnScoreTrigger();
            EventSystem.ResetEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehavior {

    public int score;

    private void Start() {
       
         EventSystem.OnScore += OnScoreChanged;
    }

    private void OnScoreChanged() {

         score++;
    }
}
```

Note: nullifying the static variables is sometimes important because they are not a components so they might not distroy or nullify their instance on scene reload so it sometimes through a null reference error just beware of that anyways...

Hope it helps... Happy coding :)

Comment: The guy below mentioned Scriptable Object, does this work for my situation too :vv?

Comment: @Khoaoaoa, Yes the scriptable object method works as well too but... it will be a unity's object so basically what I mean to say is that it will work for your use case right now but you can't use it outside unity (if you need to) so if you detach a class completly from unity like the way I told you above, it can be used in any engine that uses c# so thats just a good practice to do thats it nothing much more magical because behavior would be exact same so you need to decide wether you want your event system to be linked and dependant upon unity or you want to make it as generic as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require an object to be a component, you could do one of the following:

Create a [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) instance. The object is still part of the Unity lifecycle and can be customized via serialization, but is essentially just "an asset" and not a component on a prefab that needs to be spawned first.

If you do not need any communication with Unity (no serialization, no access via inspector, etc.) you can simply create a good 'ol class without inheritance. You can make it static or create a static instance (similar to what you did in Awake).

Comment: So about my situation, which do you think is better, a scriptable object or a normal class ?